# How to store OpenAI embeddings in Redis Vector Database?

Tags: database, azure, vector, redis, vector-database

I've gone through Azure and Redis websites and understood that Redis can be used to store Cache. I want to store OpenAI embeddings in Redis Vector Database.

I signed up for free trail account of Redis cloud version. I'm able to connect to the DB using some python code given in home page of my Redis cloud version. Now I'm stuck. I don't know how to proceed further.

I've gone through following websites:
https://redis.io/docs/about/ 
https://redis.com/solutions/use-cases/vector-database/

They talk about redis cache and redis vector database. But I was not able to find what I'm searching for.

I've gone through some Azure links as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-import-export-data

Even this link talks only about cache for redis.

I found some terms like Redis, Redis Vector Database, Azure Cache for Redis, Azure Redis enterprise. Are these terms same?

How to store embeddings (specifically OpenAI) in Redis Vector Database? Also, how to host this Redis Vector Database on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

> Redis, Redis Vector Database, Azure Cache for Redis, Azure Redis enterprise. Are these terms same?

- Redis is an opensource caching technology
- Azure Cache for Redis is the Azure SaaS implementation of Redis
- Azure Redis Enterprise is an enterprise grade Azure SaaS implementation of Redis with additional functionality such as RediSearch and with an SLA

You will need an implementation of Redis Cache WITH RediSearch.  You will save your embeddings into Redis and perform a "vector similarity search"

Read this link:  https://mlops.community/vector-similarity-search-from-basics-to-production/

Comment: Hi @TheeUnderdog
Thanks for the answer. I've gone through the given links as well as some other links as well.
Now I've some more questions:
1. For production scenarios, do I need to get an Azure Redis Enterprise resource to store embeddings and perform vector similarity search?
2. I've subscribed for free trail of Azure Redis Cloud version. With the help of above links, I'm able to store some random numpy array as embeddings in redis vector database, but all the search queries are failing. I've raised a github issue as well: https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/3526

Comment: Can you please provide me resources to understand how to properly query/search vectors in a 'Redis Azure Cloud free trail vector database'

Comment: see: https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/vectors/

Comment: if you want to get started with Redis Vector similarity the easiest way is either Redis Stack (https://redis.io/download/) or a free database on Redis Cloud (https://redis.com/try-free/) and RedisInsight as a companion (app stores or redis.com/redisinsight) It contains some guides